# Should I centralised host my images for 3rd party uses?

Tags: storage

In the past I have had a flickr account with all my images, then something changed with Flickr, like they once changed a policy or the site had some technical glitch and where I had been referencing the images on my blog no longer linked properly.

Although I managed to rectify the issue, I was wondering if anyone is in the practice of having a centralised place for hosting images online - backing up is common but are those images then linkable for displaying on blogs etc?

Update:  you might want to send links to the images for a competition / residency or as an example of your work, or as a place where clients can access your images if they have the rights and can repeatedly use your work. Or if a 3rd party article wants to display your images - you still have control etc.

Comment: When you trust your work to a third party you have no control. And Flickr? They're not serious about photography since Marissa Mayer stated that "there's no such thing as a professional photographer." Please friend, go to Amazon, buy a cheap external hard drive, and take responsibility for your own precious images. And keep two backups, one updated daily and one offsite, updated weekly.

Comment: "Worth it" compared to what?

Comment: Worth it compared to using something like Flickr. In my own experience using Flickr was in the long term not a good use of my efforts. Being a beginner photographer I didn't know any better. However, a better use of my efforts might have been to devote more time to my own offline system which I'm having to do later on. Problem with things like Flickr is that they become a dumping ground for everything and end up just being a repository of devalued content.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about website architecture and not photography.

Comment: Not quite about website architecture as you might want to send links to the images for a competition / residency or as an example of your work, or as a place where clients can access your images if they have the rights and can repeatedly use your work. Or if a 3rd party article wants to display your images - you still have control etc.

Comment: @dpollitt question updated.

Comment: On Flickr, setting a photo to private will change the URL. Other than that, AFAIK the image URLs are fixed. I have had several Flickr photos linked from my blog for years, they are still working fine.

Comment: Flickr is aimed at people who want to show their photos publically 'socially' whereas I just needed somewhere central where I can reference images from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not have been a technical glitch with Flickr. They might just have changed their site structure - you can't rely on a free third party service to guarantee a 'permalink' type structure in their site.

Your question doesn't seem to relate to backups as such, I presume you've got some sort of backup system in place already, and that you are exclusively asking about an easy way to share images.

The best way to be sure that a link you use isn't going to break is to purchase your own hosting. This is the only way you can really guarantee anything (excepting the fact that you are dependent on your hosting service not having issues). Paid hosting with your own domain is relatively cheap. You can use various off-the-shelf and open source gallery type sites, Wordpress, Joomla or any other content management system. Obviously the trade-off is that it's up to you to configure it and maintain it. If you're prepared to spend a bit of time though, a simple self-hosted Wordpress site may be worth creating.

This isn't a free solution, but it doesn't have to be expensive, but at the end of the day, you need to have some sort of solution that you have control over.